# Refreshing PivotTable error - Unable to refresh data type

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I try to refresh a set of PivotTable using Refresh All I get the following message;

```
Unable to refresh data types
```

I have read that this is to do with whether or not you have an internet connection, which was off, when I turn it on then it works. However, as a alternative I also have this code to refresh the Pivot Tables;

> ```
> For Each SheetPivotTables In Sheets("Analysis").PivotTables
>
>     SheetPivotTables.RefreshTable
>     
> Next SheetPivotTables
> ```

Which works regardless of internet availability, I also noticed that if you refresh one table at a time it's fine. Is there a way to resolve the error message, I'm using Excel 365.

Comment: What kind of data source did you use? How did you create the connection?

Comment: It's an Excel table. Even if I create a small table with two columns and use that as the source of the Pivot Table the error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving file to Excel Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Trusted Locations
Add a a location whereever you want.
Don't use the locations here. I stored my macro enabled files to one of excel's trusted locations and opened it and it opens all your excel files.
So create your own Trusted Location.

Answer (score 0):

Right click table tab >view code.
Click, (General) > Worksheet
To right dropdown click Change.
Type this:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim pc In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches

Next

End Sub

Do this to all your Tables that have PivotTables.